# Спавнится много объектов вместо одного Unity 3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

вот такая проблема у меня:
Создал пустой объект "Cube Spawner" и прикрепил к нему скрипт "CubeSpawner":

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CubeSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject cube;
    bool ready = false;
    Transform pos;
    public float delay;

    private void Start()
    {
        pos = GetComponent<Transform>();
        StartCoroutine(SpawnCube());
        Instantiate(cube);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Cube")
        {
            ready = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Cube")
        {
            ready = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if(other.tag == "Cube")
        {
            ready = true;
            Instantiate(cube);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator SpawnCube()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        if (ready == true)
        {
            float Xpos = pos.position.x;
            float Ypos = pos.position.y;
            float Zpos = pos.position.z;
            ready = false;
            Instantiate(cube, new Vector3(Xpos, Ypos, Zpos), Quaternion.identity);
        }
        StartCoroutine(SpawnCube());
    }
}
```

В начале у меня появляется один куб(всё пока идёт нормально) с анимацией, когда нажимаю "W" куб падает и срабатывает триггер, пропадания объекта со спавнера. Далее появляется 2 куба с анимацией, после нажатия "W" и больше, и больше...
[image: Начало]
[image: Один лишний куб и так будет больше]

Вот сам скрипт префаба:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;

public class Cubecontroller : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool _isPlayable;
    Rigidbody rb;

    private void Start()
    {
        _isPlayable = true;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        CubeReaction();
    }

    private void CubeReaction()
    {
        if (_isPlayable == true && Input.GetKeyDown("w"))
        {
            _isPlayable = false;
            rb.isKinematic = false;
            Destroy(GetComponent<Animator>());
        }
    }
}
```

Нужно, чтобы спавнился один куб, можете помочь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Схема с коллайдерами и тегами хлипкая, запутанная и не нужная.

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]

public class CubeSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    // поля внутренней кухни не должны быть публичные
    // поля SerializeField отражены в инспекторе
    [SerializeField] private Cube _cubeTemplate;
    // сколько кубу нужно пролететь до спавна следующего
    [SerializeField] private float _respawnDeltaY = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _fallKey = KeyCode.W;
    private Transform _transform;
    private Cube _currentCube;
    
    private void Awake ()
    {
        _transform = transform;
        SpawnCurrentCube();
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        if (_currentCube != null && Input.GetKeyDown(_fallKey))
        {
            _currentCube.Fall();
            StartCoroutine(RespawnCubeCoroutine(_currentCube.transform));
            _currentCube = null;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator RespawnCubeCoroutine (Transform target)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (target.position.y < _transform.position.y-_respawnDeltaY)
                break; // выход из цикла
            yield return null; // каждый кадр
        }
        SpawnCurrentCube();
    }

    private void SpawnCurrentCube ()
    {
        GameObject NewCube = Instantiate(_cubeTemplate.gameObject);
        NewCube.transform.position = _transform.position;
        _currentCube = NewCube.GetComponent<Cube>();
    }
}
```

---

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]

public class Cube : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody _body;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    public void Fall ()
    {
        _body.isKinematic = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Всё отлично, спасибо! Только я в "CubeSpawner" убрал  "_currentCube = null;"
Из за этой строки выводилась ошибка в консоли Unity.

Comment: Мой косяк. Эта строчка нужна, что бы команда нажатия не срабатывала, пока следующий куб не появится. Просто строчка должна быть после `StartCoroutine`.